# MQTT and Junit - looking for an embedded MQTT broker

Tags: java, junit, mqtt

I need to write some unit tests for my MQTT client java application. What is the embedded broker's implementation can be used ?
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably start with Mosquette

https://github.com/andsel/moquette

Comment: Hi, Even I am trying to do this. Any update or reference how to deal with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please ask a new question with what you have already tried and what problem you have hit, especially since this one has been closed